# How can the past, the present and the future coexist at the same time?

Tags: spacetime, relativity, causality, determinism, time-travel

We all heard it many times, [the theory of Time](http://everythingforever.com/einstein.htm) suggest it is parallel rather than being linear. This leaves the door opened for alternate realities and well, immortality.

However, even after reading tones of lines and watching tones of documentaries, I still cannot understand how it makes sense while everybody in the scientific community seems to accept a theory they yet cannot prove.

I don't understand how the past, present and the future can exist at the same time. I cannot warp my head around the idea that our younger and grown selves are somehow "living" at the same time creating different versions of ourselves in an infinite loop that is...

How can the 5 year old me still be out there while the 28 year old me is here? That means the 56 year old me is already out there?

Does it mean that our lives are already predefined? I have so many questions but I will end it here in order to stay relevant to the topic.

Comment: Where are you getting all this information from?

Comment: @PeterR: Updated with sources. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I have a final exam in 3 hours, that is what I need now: some past and some future :)

Comment: None of what you are saying has anything to do with science.

Comment: "while everybody in the scientific community seems to accept a theory they yet cannot prove." FALSE. It is probably "everybody in the science fiction community" that you mean. All these logical speculations should be addressed to people who are trying to write science fiction that logically hangs together. "Tons of words ( or videos) do not science make". Einstein in the link is not talking of multiple worlds and such stuff. Just of the way he viewed the mathematics of general relativity.

Comment: [See also here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1615).

Answer (score 6):

This is a good question and more philosophical in nature: Philosophy SE *may* be a better home for this question (there are indeed solid and knowledgeable physicist who loiter at that site). Essentially you are talking about the [Eternalist or Perdurist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time)) conception of time - if you've not heard these terms before they may give you some terms to search by. Famous living subscribers to it include [Hilary Putnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilary_Putnam). Not so famous ones include the person writing these words.

But the essential idea is this: since simultaneous is a relative notion (different observers in different motion states will disagree on whether two events are simultaneous and even, for some pairs of observers, disagree about the time order of events), it makes little sense to say that the past, as defined by one particular observer, doesn't exist given that this past will be in the future of some relatively moving observer. Likewise for the future of any given observer. There could be, theoretically, an observer in a relative motion state to you whose "present" time slice includes the five year old you. However, that does not mean you could communicate with the five year old you through this observer (see below). It thus becomes difficult to say what is "real" or "extant"- by whose standpoint would you define the existence of things?

Physicists don't generally think to these terms: the notions of "real" and "extant" in this context are more complicated than needed: physics simply either describes the outcomes of experiments or tries to find rules to foretell those outcomes. It is however true that one set of these outcome-foretelling rules, namely special and general relativity, take on their simplest description if you think of spacetime as a unified whole (unified by the geometrical notion of a spacetime [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)).

**Some Technical Details**

Let's look at some technical details about the above, and we'll see why most of the above discussion lies outside physics and is needfully philosophical and why you can't talk to or see your five year old self.

1. Discussion of Eternalism is usually made in *flat, or Minkowski, spacetime*. There are three reasons for this: (1) it is a very good approximation (large scale) to our own universe (2) it is simple and (3) it is a valid solution to the vacuum Einstein field equations. So deductions made from it are properties of gravitation theory;
2. We assume the experimentally supported observation that there are no time machines. You cannot communicate with your five year old self: more generally and concisely, any event in spacetime can only influence other events that lie in the the former event's future light cone. Remember I said above that for relatively moving observers may not agree on the order of events. One of the elegant properties of relativity, though, is that if event B is in the future light cone of event A, then this is true for *every* observer. Event order only changes for events that lie *outside* each other's future (or past) light cones. They lie in the so-called "elsewhere" or "elsewhen" on each other's spacetime diagrams. This is very important, for it means that we can make our everyday observation that causes do not come before effects consistent with relativity *if* we postulate that causally connected events must lie in each other's future light cones. $A$ can only be a cause of $B$ if $B$ lies in $A$'s future light cone. Indeed this postulate is the reason why relativity says that locally something cannot move faster than $c$: if it could, it could see the order of causally linked events swap and therefore a notion of causality could not be consistent with relativity.

Now, with all this out of the way, let us look at what I mean when a relatively moving observer can be "contemporary" with the five year old you. Suppose an observer is some distance away from you and begins to move towards you. Because our spacetime is flat, both observers can set up so called affine co-ordinate systems - these are roughly those defined by laying rigid measuring rods end to end to give a grid co-ordinate system. These co-ordinates transform by the Lorentz transformation when you switch to a relatively moving frame, and what the Lorentz transformation shows is that the $t=0$ hyperplane for the observer moving towards you now intersects your world line at some point in the past. Likewise, your $t=0$ plane now intersects their world line in their past. If you are space a great distance from the observer, the effect can be very large: your $t=0$ hyperplanes now intersect each other's world lines in the distant past. Over cosmological distances, this effect can easily be great enough that that past goes back to your five year old self.

None of this, unfortunately, allows you to communicate with the five year old through the moving observer as a go-between, because, although the five year old is on the observer's $t=0$ timeslice, they are not in the observer's future light cone. So that, by the time the observer reached you, you would have aged more than 28-5 years, so the effect cannot be used to visit or communicate with your 5 year old self or indeed any younger version of you. Indeed, if causality is true, no experiment done by the five year old you can be influenced by choices that you make as a 28 year old (the converse, of course does not hold: the five year old can most certainly influence the 28 year old by the choices she makes - in technical jargon - the five year old has a causal, forwards-in-time-pointing link with the 28 year old).

So you can see that the questions addressed by Eternalistic thinking are essentially about the "reality", or otherwise, from the standpoint of any observer, of events that lie *outside* that observer's future and past light cone. As we have seen, if causality is true, then no experiment can shed light on the answer to this question and so the question becomes one outside physics and in the realm of philosophy. Events that are "contemporary"(on our $t=0$ hyperplane in flat spacetime) with us but at a distance from us cannot be influenced by us, by the universal speed limit $c$. Eternalism essentially asserts that these events do have a reality, even if if can't be tested by physics. Reasons for subscribing to an Eternalistic standpoint include **(1)** not wanting to have "reality" being an observer-dependent notion (this doesn't bother physics, because the events in question cannot be probed by experiment and no two observers that can eventually communicate can disagree about mutually observed events), **(2)** *some* events outside our future light cone *can* influence events in their future light cones that will, far enough into the future, intersect our future light light cone. So to deny their reality seems a little weird. I liken this very much to the philosophical position that rejects solipsism: we cannot probe certain events experimentally now, but we may eventually see their effects, so it seems simplest to ascribe to those antecedent events a reality in the same way the one cannot prove one is not the only person in the universe and all else their imaginings, but the simplest explanation for the World we see is that there are indeed other people. As Richard Gregory once quipped: solipsists were welcome to study in his department, but they must abide by the special solipsist's law that they must always buy the beer for everyone on Friday evenings.

As for whether all this implies that the Universe is "predefined" or "fore-ordained" that is indeed a new question. A literal reading of the general relativistic description above seems to say so, but another branch of physics, quantum mechanics and quantum field theory, seems to say that the notion of an experiment's outcome's existing before the experiment is done is a meaningless notion. You can begin your research into this new question by looking up the notion of [Counterfactual Definiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_definiteness).

Comment: While I usually think highly of your posts, some of this is simply false. There is no observer in the entire universe for whom the five year old you still exists. There may be observers who have captured a few photons emitted by the five year old you in their telescopes or who will some time in your future, but that's it. The five year old you has existed once and is now gone forever in every observer system. Nobody will ever be able to visit the five year old you, again. Any other way of looking at it is bad philosophy and completely false physics.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think this is a little premature before a full solution to the "problem of the now". From a physics standpoint, questions like these are tantamount to asking what exists outside one's future light cone, or whether two observers with no possible causal link can talk about each other's existence and are thus completely moot: there is no experiment either observer can do to answer them. That's why most of this question is outside the realm of physics. Eternalism is a non-testable interpretation outside physics, just as the soundness or unsoundness of solipsism (which is a not ...

Comment: @CuriousOne ... an unlike problem in my opinion) is utterly untestable. Yet, as Richard Gregory once quipped, solipsists were quite welcome in his department as long as they heeded one rule for solipsists: on Friday evenings they must buy all the beer for everyone, since it clearly made no difference to them from their standpoint. Anyhow, hope you had a great Xmas BTW and I look forward to seeing more of you next year.

Comment: You made the claim that somebody could still visit the five year old you... which would only be possible with at time machine. I think we can put that safely outside of both physics and sound philosophy. I have no idea how solipsism and beer entered the arena...

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't read my answer like that and I certainly don't mean it to be read that way. As you would know, the relatively moving observer with the five year old in their "contemporary" timeslice could have no causal connexion with the 28 year old.

Comment: Maybe you could reformulate your answer in a way that makes it clear what you actually mean? As written it clearly implies the need for time travel. To me the word simultaneous only makes sense for identical space(time) points. I am not in any way, shape or form simultaneous with events in Andromeda. If I wanted to be, I would have to go there.

Comment: @CuriousOne See edits

Comment: Your past is still your past for all observers. Nobody can visit the five year old you without a time machine. Why do you find it so hard to say that in one sentence? On some level I find your post very hard to understand. If something can't be tested then it's not science. Period. Let's not talk about non-science on a science site, OK? If you want to talk about philosophy  (as bad as it may be), why not take it to a philosophy site?

Comment: @CuriousOne As I began my post, "...more philosophical in nature: Philosophy SE may be a better home ...". Yes I agree, *most* of this post is philosophy, not science, and I have been at pains to say that and moreover why it is not science: because it is asking questions about things that are outside the observable universe. The physics content of the post is the explanation of why the question lies outside physics. I'm very wary of limiting discussions to known physics although I agree one must be clear to ken when one is outside known physics. To give a simple example: .....

Comment: @CuriousOne ....when I was in my teens, scientists would get very heated about the question of "before the big bang". The received wisdom was that it was meaningless to ask this question, and physicists would bristle and look down on those who asked it. It *may well* be still the correct viewpoint - indeed held by many contemporary scientists whom I respect - but now we are not so sure. Respected scientists do delve into this question. Something else that should be clear from this post about me is that I do not subscribe to a logical positivist standpoint, although I think this standpoint ...

Comment: All of this is philosophy unless you can present us with a time machine. Sorry... like I said, I usually like your posts, but with this one you have dug a hole and you are digging it deeper. Please stop digging.

Comment: @CuriousOne ... IS the correct one to decide whether something is science or philosophy.

Comment: We are still pretty sure that it is meaningless to ask what was before the big bang. Not one model I know about preserves anything but trivial thermodynamic information, which is akin to saying "there was something". Of course there was something.

Comment: NATURE is the one to decide. If you talk about things that nature does not agree with (like time machines), then you have left the natural sciences.

Comment: @CuriousOne I have flagged the post to be moved to Philosophy SE

Comment: OK. That's a constructive solution.

Answer (score -1):

The five year old you could theoretically be seen to 'exist' to an observer who was living 23 light years away (if they could build a telescope big enough... But realistically, It would have to be so big that it's not possible)

This is because light bouncing off your body will have taken 23 years to reach the observer, travelling at the speed of light. If you were also watching the observer with an impossibly massive telescope, and you saw them holding up a sign saying 'I can see your five-year old self', you would then have to be 51.

But in terms of your local frame of self-reference, the only real time there is is the time your brain interprets as 'now' (this is itself an illusion as our brain delays the experience of sound so it goes in sync with our perception of image, and other such tricks.)

As for your future - that simply hasn't happened yet, not from any frame of reference currently known. There are probabilities and likelihoods, but no absolute certainties.

Answer (score -3):

I'll keep it simple. If time could be in more than 1 place at the same time, then why did the beginning Big Bang start at the smallest possible point in space(time)? Because time must exist in one place at a time. Makes sense eh? Time is fast I'll give it that but its not faster than time, it's not already in the future until it's that time.

Comment: The big bang didn't start in one point. Where did you read that?

Comment: It started the size of quark.  I only know what experts have said.

Comment: I don't know of any expert who made that claim in earnest. Can you give me a citation? In any case, the size of a quark is not even a well defined concept. Quarks don't have a size. They are point objects in the current theory and general relativity doesn't make that prediction.

Comment: It was probably a 'brief history of the universe' by hawking. It's the first of my books. I was surprised to hear this too. Quarks are obviously small and can't use anything smaller to reference. I thought it was a golf ball or softball size but not the case. If not hawking maybe Lawerence Kruss or just maybe 'the 4% universe', or last guess is Kip Thornes 'interstellar'. I can't remember where but I didn't make it up.

Comment: I didn't read that book and I do not think of its content as serious claims made by an expert. Did you see a peer reviewed science paper by Hawking in which he makes that claim? The same applies to Krauss or Kip Thorne's work. If they have written this in a science paper it will come with some sort of explanation under what assumption one can derive this in some theory. That doesn't mean the universe actually did whatever that theory says it did.

Comment: I did not think more of it, and it was just general science for us new folks. Never thought to question it.

Comment: What do you know of its beginning ?

Comment: I see... OK. Yes, I agree, these random snippets of bad science, often linked to some overly eager book sales are, unfortunately, around and they seem to be increasing in frequency. They have not much, if anything, in common with the details one can find in physics textbooks and well written papers.

Comment: Of the beginnings of the universe? I do know that we do not know ANYTHING about it. We have a fairly good idea what may have happened a little bit later and there are some serious hints, even from the side of our current theory, that the big bang is not the actual beginning, it's just a veil behind which we most likely won't be able to peek.

Comment: So we don't know where the bang got its power? My obsession with that is what began my quest for all I could learn. So what text book is better at explaining the real science? Instead of these fancy particle physics story books that are not really difficult.

Comment: Where does the big bang gets is power source from? From whatever caused the big bang, presumably. If you want the "real science" you will have to read the entire cosmology physics literature, including observational astronomy papers, theoretical and experimental general relativity, quantum gravity and all of the latest particle physics stuff. What do you need to understand those? A PhD in physics with active experience in cosmology would be the minimum requirement but having working experience in at least one of these fields will do for starters, too. Ten years 24/7 and you will be good.

Comment: I have learned a lot. Obviously it's easy to learn when the math is already done.  I'm fairly familiar with the Standard Model and if we find the symmetrical particles it would be a hell of a discovery and legitimize string theory.  I also know of the hierarchical  problem. Can't spell it just yet. I had no idea I would have to learn so much more than cosmology when I started. I'm just learning what I have to learn next. So yes Quantum Mechanics is not what I expected but that's what I am trying to learn now.

Comment: You are learning quantum mechanics after you have familiarized yourself with the standard model? That's about as likely as you reading Tolstoi's original manuscript of "War and Peace" before learning to do your ABCs in English. Don't get me wrong, but that's not how one can learn physics.

Comment: Yea I realized this too.  I had to back track, but YouTube has good professors to catch-up. I didn't know what to expect I just started reading.

Comment: OK... if that makes you happy. :-)

Comment: Yea that's why I started, to not be sad. Broke up with fiancé and kept busy studying space stuff, but got too obsessed with knowing what I did not know at all. Seems like nobody knows unless they want too.